# Android Kotlin - Custom View not showing right in Design editor

Tags: android, kotlin

The problem is this. I build a custom edit text view. It has a textView and an editText.

This is how it looks like:

[image]
This is the class that manages the custom editText:

```
class CustomEditText @JvmOverloads constructor(
        context: Context,
        attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
        defStyle: Int = 0
) : ConstraintLayout(context,attrs, defStyle) {
    init {
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_edit_text, this, true)

        // Set invisible by default. This label will be shown if the user enter text into the EditText
        CustomEditText_Title.visibility = View.INVISIBLE

        CustomEditText_EditText.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {}

            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}

            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
                if (count > 0) {
                    CustomEditText_Title.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                } else {
                    CustomEditText_Title.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                }
            }
        })

        attrs?.let {
            val typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(it, R.styleable.custom_edit_text_attributes, 0, 0)

            val title = resources.getText(typedArray.getResourceId(R.styleable.custom_edit_text_attributes_custom_edit_text_title, R.string.custom_edittext_default_title))
            val hint = resources.getText(typedArray.getResourceId(R.styleable.custom_edit_text_attributes_custom_edit_text_hint, R.string.custom_edittext_default_hint))
            val input_type = resources.getText(typedArray.getResourceId(R.styleable.custom_edit_text_attributes_custom_edit_text_input_type, R.string.custom_edittext_input_type_text))

            CustomEditText_Title.text = title
            CustomEditText_EditText.hint = hint

            when(input_type) {
                "0" -> CustomEditText_EditText.inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT
                "1" -> CustomEditText_EditText.inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER or InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_NORMAL
                "2" -> CustomEditText_EditText.inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT or InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS
                "3" -> {
                    CustomEditText_EditText.inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT or InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD

                    val typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.font.gothamrnd_book)
                    CustomEditText_EditText.typeface = typeface
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

In the constructor, I made a workaround to set the inputType for the editText. This is because I could not figure it out how to use an android:inputType in styleable attributes (I try many different options but all of them give as a result an inflate error).

The problem is this:

I use a string to configure the inputType:

```
when(input_type) {
                    "0" -> CustomEditText_EditText.inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT
                    "1" -> CustomEditText_EditText.inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER or InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_NORMAL
                    "2" -> CustomEditText_EditText.inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT or InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS
                    "3" -> {
                        CustomEditText_EditText.inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT or InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD

                        val typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.font.gothamrnd_book)
                        CustomEditText_EditText.typeface = typeface
                    }
                }
```

But if a choose the "3" type, which is password type in the Design view, it shows wrong. It uses all the screen, no the designated area.
If I change it, for example, to text type, it shows right.

I'm using Kotlin and minimum SDK 21.

Do anyone know why could this be happening?

Thanks guys!!

Comment: Y not you try [TextInputEditText](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputEditText) in android to acheive same behaviour. [Reference](https://medium.com/@Gryzor/styling-textinputlayout-and-textinputedittext-on-android-9ab786bef7af).

Comment: It's because I can't customize it the way I want it. So I decided to build it by myself.

Comment: Can anybody help me with this? I am stuck :(

Comment: Did you find the solution for this? I am facing the same issue. View is creating but not showing up in the editor window.

Comment: I do not. I'm still facing this error after a year o so. I changed it to different components ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Late reply.

This has to do something with your `@JvmOverloads`.

You can read more about that here: https://medium.com/@mmlodawski/https-medium-com-mmlodawski-do-not-always-trust-jvmoverloads-5251f1ad2cfe

I was also trying to create a custom EditText and faced the same problem. I was also using `@JvmOverloads`. After going through this article, I changed it to the secondary constructor in Kotlin, and it started working right away.